# Download large files from server using iis hosted WCF

Tags: wcf, large-files

I need to write a WCF method for downloading large file from server like around 150mb.
Can anyone suggest the best method to use? any code samples?

Comment: Streaming - do a search on Google for WCF streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stream the data.

The contract would look like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
public interface IStreamedService
{
   [OperationContract]
   Stream RequestInfo(string query);
}
```

The configuration would be:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streamed"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

You then need to implement the contract with code that reads the file and returns the contents as a stream.